# NSString get file as string by removing path

Tags: objective-c, string

If i have a string like /Users/me/Documents/code/maccode/myApp/Icon.png

what should I do to be left only with "Icon.png"?

Using xcode and programming a mac application with objective c.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Read the NSString documentation. *Hint:* There is a "Working with Paths" sections.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
NSString *filename = @"/Users/me/Documents/code/maccode/myApp/Icon.png";
NSString *path = [filename lastPathComponent];
```

That will give you `Icon.png`

Comment: You know what, it makes sense that this is what OP wanted. I completely misinterpreted that. +1

Comment: Yeah I didnt realize that actually did what it did.